# В конфигурацию Intellij Idea не добавляется Tomcat

Tags: intellij-idea, tomcat, настройка

Idea при запуске моего приложения пишет ошибку Error running Application: The selected directory is not a TomEE home.
Скачала Tomcat, распаковала, он запускается - по ссылке http://localhost:8080/ открывается страница Tomcata. В настройках Idea прописываю путь к папке с Tomcat, а он ошибку выдает. Помогите плиз, что делаю не так?

[image: Фото ишибки в Idea:]

[image: Папка с Tomcat]

Comment: Судя по первому скрину, в Idea Вы пытаетесь добавить TomcatEE (TomEE), а скачали обычный томкат. то есть, для добавления не тот томкат просто выбрали

Comment: так и есть, спасибо